# python parsing a datetime with a timezone

Tags: python, date, time

I am trying to parse an string from a log file in the format: `2011-06-27 10:29:56+0200`

If I use `datetime.datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')` I get `ValueError("'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'")` thrown

How can I parse a date in this format?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458705/flexible-english-date-phrase-library-for-python

Comment: related: [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

Answer (score 8):

Try using [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

```
from dateutil.parser import parse    
dt = parse("2011-06-27 10:29:56+0200")
```