# Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, rfc3339

I am trying to convert time-stamps of the format "2012-07-24T23:14:29-07:00" 
to datetime objects in python using strptime method. The problem is with the time offset at the end(-07:00). Without the offset i can successfully do

```
time_str = "2012-07-24T23:14:29"

time_obj=datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

But with the offset i tried

```
time_str = "2012-07-24T23:14:29-07:00"

time_obj=datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%z').
```

But it gives a Value error saying "z" is a bad directive.

Any ideas for a work around?

Comment: related: [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/4279)

Comment: related: [Convert an RFC 3339 time to a standard Python timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1941927/4279)

Comment: Change `-%z` to `%z`. The `-` (or `+`) is part of the offset.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The Python 2 `strptime()` function indeed does not support the `%z` format for timezones (because the underlying [`time.strptime()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) doesn't support it). You have two options:

- Ignore the timezone when parsing with `strptime`:

  ```
  time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str[:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
  ```
- use the [`dateutil` module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil), it's parse function *does* deal with timezones:

  ```
  from dateutil.parser import parse
  time_obj = parse(time_str)
  ```

Quick demo on the command prompt:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("2012-07-24T23:14:29-07:00")
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 24, 23, 14, 29, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))
```

You could also upgrade to Python 3.2 or newer, where timezone support has been improved to the point that `%z` would work, provided you remove the last `:` from the input, and the `-` from before the `%z`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time_str = "2012-07-24T23:14:29-07:00"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 500, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 337, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2012-07-24T23:14:29-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
>>> ''.join(time_str.rsplit(':', 1))
'2012-07-24T23:14:29-0700'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join(time_str.rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 24, 23, 14, 29, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200)))
```

Comment: parse is unfortunately not happy wuith the default apache log date parser.parse('24/Jun/2015:00:01:03 +0200')

Comment: So this wins the internet, i.e. parses happily apache log file timestamps `parser.parse('24/Jun/2015:00:01:03 +0200'.replace(':',' ',1))`

Answer (score 30):

In Python 3.7+:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_str = "2012-07-24T23:14:29-07:00"
dt_aware = datetime.fromisoformat(time_str)
print(dt_aware.isoformat('T'))
# -> 2012-07-24T23:14:29-07:00
```

In Python 3.2+:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_str = "2012-07-24T23:14:29-0700"
dt_aware = datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(dt_aware.isoformat('T'))
# -> 2012-07-24T23:14:29-07:00
```

Note: Before Python 3.7 this variant didn't support `:` in the `-0700` part (both formats are allowed by [rfc 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6)). See [datetime: add ability to parse RFC 3339 dates and times](http://bugs.python.org/issue15873).

On older Python versions such as Python 2.7, you could parse the utc offset manually:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_str = "2012-07-24T23:14:29-0700"
# split the utc offset part
naive_time_str, offset_str = time_str[:-5], time_str[-5:]
# parse the naive date/time part
naive_dt = datetime.strptime(naive_time_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
# parse the utc offset
offset = int(offset_str[-4:-2])*60 + int(offset_str[-2:])
if offset_str[0] == "-":
   offset = -offset
dt = naive_dt.replace(tzinfo=FixedOffset(offset))
print(dt.isoformat('T'))
```

where [`FixedOffset` class is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122493/4279).

Answer (score 6):

## `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format...`

(note: I have to stick to python 2.7 in my case)

I have had a similar problem parsing commit dates from the output of `git log --date=iso8601` which actually isn't the ISO8601 format (hence the addition of `--date=iso8601-strict` in a later version).

Since I am using `django` I can leverage the utilities there.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateparse.py

```
>>> from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
>>> parse_datetime('2013-07-23T15:10:59.342107+01:00')
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 23, 15, 10, 59, 342107, tzinfo=+0100)
```

Instead of `strptime` you could use your own regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

With python 3.5.2
To convert `26 Sep 2000 05:11:00 -0700`

```
from datetime import datetime    
dt_obj = datetime.strptime("26 Sep 2000 05:11:00 -0700", '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

To convert `2012-07-24T23:14:29 -0700`

```
dt_obj = datetime.strptime('2012-07-24T23:14:29 -0700', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z')
```

Python 3.5.2 doesn't support -07:00 time offset ':' should be removed