# Convert UTC time to python datetime

Tags: python, datetime, utc, rfc3339

I have numerous UTC time stamps in the following format:
`2012-04-30T23:08:56+00:00`
I want to convert them to python datetime objects but am having trouble.

My code:

```
for time in data:
    pythondata[i]=datetime.strptime(time,"%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00")
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2012-03-01T00:05:55+00:00' does not match format '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00'
```

It looks like I have the proper format, so why doesn't this work?

Comment: related: [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the year marker in your time format string to `%Y`:

```
time = '2012-03-01T00:05:55+00:00'
datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00")
# => datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 5, 55)
```

See [`strftime()` and `strptime()` behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [python-dateutil library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil), it allows conversion of multiple datetime formats from raw strings into datetime objects with/without timezone set

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse('2012-04-30T23:08:56+00:00')

datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 30, 23, 8, 56, tzinfo=tzutc())
```