# convert a string to datetime format

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

How should I fix this?

error is:

```
ValueError: time data '2016-10-20 03:43:11+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
```

code is:

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"
dt = datetime.strptime(row['Time'], fmt)
```

Comment: `+00:00` doesn't match `%z` because it has a colon in it.  If you can count on your data always being formatted properly you can do `datetime.strptime(row['Time'][:22] + row['Time'][23:], fmt)`.

Comment: you could also change your `fmt` as shown below, provided your have constant date formatting.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski you are right , apologies :) I did a typo in my test code and I just saw it!

Comment: @stucash: It all depends whether OP's dates have any context that needs to be preserved.  There are lots of cases where that time zone doesn't matter.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yes, I guess if the date format shown above is what OP wanted to preserve, we could just change the `fmt` and this depends on whether the data has a constant format.

Answer (score 1):

a bit of search would give you some nice [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662789/convert-utc-time-to-python-datetime).

**first option**:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

t = '2016-10-20 03:43:11+00:00'
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00:00"
d = dt.strptime(t, fmt)

# output datetime.datetime(2016,10,20,3,43,11)
```

**second option**:

```
from dateutil import parser as psr

t = '2016-10-20 03:43:11+00:00'

d = psr.parse(t)

# output datetime.datetime(2016,10,20,3,43,11, tzinfo=tzutc())
```