# Trying to convert timestamp into milliseconds in Python. Got format error

Tags: python, timestamp, strptime

I am trying to convert a timestamp in the format of *2020-07-27T23:00:53+00:00* to milliseconds using the following line of code

```
utc_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-07-27T23:00:53+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
milsec = utc_time.timestamp() * 1000
```

It works fine on my local system but when I try to run the code on a remote system which is in the same timezone as I am, I get the error

> *time data '2020-07-27T23:00:53+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'*.

Is there anything that I should be aware of here? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC time to python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662789/convert-utc-time-to-python-datetime)

Comment: @Sushanth I don't have that error. They used "y" instead of "Y". Mine is "Y". Also, the code runs fine on my local system.

Comment: ``datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-07-27T23:00:53+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00')`` ?

Comment: @Sushanth That solves it, if it is 00:00 at the end of the timestamp but not if they are not 00:00.

Comment: What are the timezone and locales settings on both systems? Consider stripping off TZ before you parse

Comment: @RobRaymond  They both give the same output for time.tzname

Comment: Since `strptime` uses the system's C library, the behaviour of %z can be different on different systems. If you have Python >= 3.7 available, you could try to parse via `datetime.fromisoformat('string')`.

Comment: The code mentioned above works fine for me with no errors - Python3.8.0~win32

Comment: @MrFuppes your solution worked. I guess you're right on the behaviour of %z being different on different systems.