# How to convert datetime string with +00:00 to datetime

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert this string to a datetime object in Python. I don't understand the time part of the string '+00:00'. What does that mean and how do I format this string?  '2021-01-04 04:00:00+00:00'

Thank you

Comment: It's mean timezone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC time to python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662789/convert-utc-time-to-python-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), that is the timezone indicator. `+00:00` represents UTC.

The [string format indicator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for timezone is `%z`.

> %z | UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (empty string if the object is naive).