# Python strptime isoformat template

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timestamp, rfc3339

Actually i guess it is a easy question, but I could not find a answer for my datestring.

It is formated like this:

```
'2015-01-16T14:13:56+01:00'
```

I tried to parse it with:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+%Z")
datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+HH:MM")
```

This seems to be wrong because it returns it does not match.

Comment: Actually I need it for python 2.7. The linked duplicate question i already checked out, but doesn't work either.

Comment: a better duplicate would be [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: golly, perhaps yes, now that I updated that answer to cover Python 3.