# Get a datetime object from the result of str(datetime)

Tags: python, string, datetime

If I print a `datetime` object in python with a simple `print myDateTime` (or `print(myDateTime)` in python3), how can I recover the `datetime` object from the resulting string?

I could have asked "what is the python `strftime` format used by `datetime.__str__()`"?

ps: There are many questions about conversion of strings to python datetime objects. In the spirit of using stack overflow as a repository of quickly available, useful programming tips, I'm asking this since none of those questions answer this rather specific and oft needed query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[By definition, `str(datetime_obj)` is `datetime_obj.isoformat(' ')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.__str__). There is [no method that would parse the ISO 8601 format back](http://bugs.python.org/issue15873); you have to provide the format to `strptime()` explicitly:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
>>> s = str(now)
>>> s
'2015-04-06 10:31:08.256426+00:00'
>>> s[:26]
'2015-04-06 10:31:08.256426'
>>> datetime.strptime(s[:26]+s[26:].replace(':',''), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 6, 10, 31, 8, 256426, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

`%z` supports `+HHMM` but it doesn't support `+HH:MM` that is why the `replace()` call is used here.

`datetime.timezone` is available since Python 3.2. For older versions, see

- [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/4279)
- [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279).

Answer (score 1):

If the datetime object doesn't have timezone info (perhaps interpreted as UTC time), you can do something like this (python 2 in this case, but the same in python 3):

```
import datetime
unprintStrptimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print d
# produces e.g.: 2015-04-06 03:11:23.840526
dd = datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-04-06 03:11:23.840526",unprintStrptimeFmt)
print dd == d 
# produces: True
```