# error reading date time from csv using pandas

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I am using Pandas to read and process csv file. My csv file have date/time column that looks like:

```
11:59:50:322 02 10 2015 -0400 EDT
11:11:55:051 16 10 2015 -0400 EDT
00:38:37:106 02 11 2015 -0500 EST
04:15:51:600 14 11 2015 -0500 EST
04:15:51:600 14 11 2015 -0500 EST
13:43:28:540 28 11 2015 -0500 EST
09:24:12:723 14 12 2015 -0500 EST
13:28:12:346 28 12 2015 -0500 EST
```

How can I read this using python/pandas, so far what I have is this:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df['senseStartTime']),format='%H:%M:%S:%f %d %m %Y %z %Z')
```

But this is not working, though previously I was able to use the same code for another format (with a different format specifier). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is likely because versions of Python before 3.2 (I think?) had a lot of trouble with time zones, so your format string might be screwing up on the %z and %Z parts. For example, in Python 2.7:

```
In [187]: import datetime

In [188]: datetime.datetime.strptime('11:59:50:322 02 10 2015 -0400 EDT', '%H:%M:%S:%f %d %m %Y %z %Z')

ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%H:%M:%S:%f %d %m %Y %z %Z'
```

You're using pd.to_datetime instead of datetime.datetime.strptime but the underlying issues are the same, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime) for help. What I would suggest is instead of using pd.to_datetime, do something like

```
In [191]: import dateutil

In [192]: dateutil.parser.parse('11:59:50.322 02 10 2015 -0400')
Out[192]: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 10, 11, 59, 50, 322000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))
```

It should be pretty simple to chop off the timezone at the end (which is redundant since you have the offset), and change the ":" to "." between the seconds and microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Since `datetime.timezone` has become available in `Python 3.2`, you can use `%z` with `.strptime()` ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html)). Starting with:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S:%f %d %m %Y %z %Z')
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=['time_col'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

to get:

```
                           time_col
0  2015-10-02 11:59:50.322000-04:00
1  2015-10-16 11:11:55.051000-04:00
2  2015-11-02 00:38:37.106000-05:00
3  2015-11-14 04:15:51.600000-05:00
4  2015-11-14 04:15:51.600000-05:00
5  2015-11-28 13:43:28.540000-05:00
6  2015-12-14 09:24:12.723000-05:00
7  2015-12-28 13:28:12.346000-05:00
```

Comment: I've Python 2.7, would this solution work? Also, I am reading column from csv file, so I need to convert first?

Comment: You can use `.strptime` as `dateparse` function in `read_csv`. Same 3.2 caveat applies, though. If `python3` is not an option, you can still parse the elements as sketched in the other answer.