# Python. Converting string into datetime throws ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have the string:

```
import datetime
time = "2016-02-01 19:14:54+02:00"
```

And trying to convert it to datetime obj:

```
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
```

It throws exception:

```
ValueError: time data '2016-02-01 19:14:54+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
```

Could you please help me what is wrong here?

Comment: there is no correct decision by this link. I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: related: [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279)

Comment: related Python issues: [No way to generate or parse timezone as produced by datetime.isoformat()](https://bugs.python.org/issue24954) and [datetime: add ability to parse RFC 3339 dates and time](https://bugs.python.org/issue15873)

Answer (score 5):

Timezone offset `%z` should not have `:` between hours and minutes *according to the python `strptime` [specification](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).*

```
>>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-02-01 19:14:54+02:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
ValueError: time data '2016-02-01 19:14:54+02:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-02-01 19:14:54+0200", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 19, 14, 54, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)))
```

Comment: Don't blame me, blame the python or gnu guys who implemented `strptime`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
And who mentioned the iso8601 standard, anyway?

Comment: You have *Timezone offset should not have : between hours and minutes.* which is incorrect, it might not be handled by strptime but it is perfectly valid

Comment: This question is about `strptime`. You're the only one talking about the iso standard.

Comment: My answer is to the question "what is wrong here?". But I agree with your point. `dateutil` is a better solution to the problem than fixing the string and then using `strptime`.

Comment: Both `+HH`,  `+HHMM` and `+HH:MM` are valid in iso8601, by the way.  `strptime` only accepts one of them, though.

Comment: I did not say they weren't, my original comment related to saying that offsets could not contain `:`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I've edited my answer to clarify that this is a `strptime` thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your date looks like it is in [iso8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you can use [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil):

```
time = "2016-02-01 19:14:54+02:00"
from dateutil import parser

dte = parser.parse(time)
```

Output:

```
In [7]: from dateutil import parser
In [8]: time = "2016-02-01 19:14:54+02:00"
In [9]: dte = parser.parse(time)   
In [10]: dte
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 19, 14, 54, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))

In [11]: dte.utcoffset()
Out[11]: datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
```

Answer (score 2):

`strptime` will not parse [iso8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted datetime strings which have a `:` in the timezone (thanks @håken-lid), which is what your `"2016-02-01 19:14:54+02:00"` is an example of.

You can use either:

[dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) library like @padraic-cunningham suggests:

```
from dateutil import parser
time = "2016-02-01 19:14:54+02:00"
dte = parser.parse(time)   
dte
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 19, 14, 54, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))

dte.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
```

or [xml.utils](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WorkingWithTime)

```
import xml.utils.iso8601
xml.utils.iso8601.parse("2004-04-09T21:39:00-08:00")
```

or [iso8601](https://bitbucket.org/micktwomey/pyiso8601)

```
import iso8601
iso8601.parse_date("2007-01-25T12:00:00Z")
datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 25, 12, 0, tzinfo=<iso8601.Utc>)
```

Comment: . Both `+HHMM` and `+HH:MM` are valid in the iso standard, so it's not quite true that strptime will not parse the iso dateformat. It was @Padriac who suggested dateutil. But I fully agree that it is better to use a third party library over `strptime` to parse iso8601. There are several problems with python's `strptime`. For instance, it can't parse ISO week dates. And the features are not guaranteed to be the same across all operating systems, since python uses the whatever version of the C strptime function that's available.

Comment: Edited to reflect the distinction