# Comparing dates not working as expected in Python

Tags: python, date, csv

I am trying to compare a date I extracted from a csv file to the current date, to check if the difference is bigger than seven days. Here is my code:

```
with open (path) as csvfile:
    readcsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in readcsv:
        iso_ts = str(row[3])
        datum = (datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join(iso_ts.rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))

    current_time = (datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))
```

Without even comparing these I get the following error

```
File "./netapp.py", line 32, in <module>
    current_time = (datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime.datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))
TypeError: must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

I would like to check, if the data coming from the csv is older than 7 days to the current date and then do something. I know this is some problem with the format of either one of these dates, but i can not seem to figure out what it is exactly. I would be very grateful for an explanation about what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) takes a `date_string` and a `format` string and converts the datestring argument to a `datetime` object. I don't think you need to convert anything, you should be able to compare `datum` to `datetime.datetime.now()` using a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

Beware, `.now()` returns a naive `datetime` object that represents local time. Local time may be ambiguous -- do not use it for comparison. I see `%z` (utc offset) in the format string; [`.strptime()` returns a timezone-aware `datetime` object on Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime). You can't compare naive and aware datetime objects. Use `.now(timezone.utc)` to create a timezone-aware current time that can be used for comparison. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Comment: @scriptkiddie: beware, `.now()` returns a naive datetime object that represents local time. Local time may be ambiguous -- do not use it for comparison. I see `%z` (utc offset) in the format string; [`.strptime()` returns a timezone-aware datetime object on Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12281975/4279). You can't compare naive and aware datetime objects. Use `.now(timezone.utc)` to create a timezone-aware current time that can be used for comparison. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian do you mind if I throw that in my answer as an edit? I think it's a great gotcha.

Comment: @wilbur : it is a minor point (the period is 7 days) but it wouldn't hurt to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is wrong.
Try this: `current_time = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%b-%dT%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: I didn't know you could call `strftime()` directly on a `datetime` object - very cool

Comment: Generating a string is the wrong way to find out whether more than a week has passed since the given timestamp. You should do the opposite: parse the  timestamp into a date/time object and find the difference.