# change string to a datetimeobject in the form `2016-03-07 14:42:48.901013+05:30`

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have time as `2016-03-07 14:42:48.901013+05:30` but this is in the form of string. I want to have it as a datetime object type , as I want to compare it with the update_ts(auto_add_now) field of django.  Any help to achieve this will be highly appreciated.

I have tried using `x = datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%UTZ')` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you want datetime object is enough or you date including time?

Comment: I want both date and time as well as the timezone

Answer (score 2):

You should use correct format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'` and ignore timezone: ts.split('+')[0]

```
x= datetime.strptime(ts.split('+')[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

ofcouse you should handle timezone by yourself or use default one.

Also you can use `dateutil.parser.parse`:
First install the `python-dateutil` package: `pip install python-dateutil`
Then:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
x = parse(ts)
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 7, 14, 42, 48, 901013, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800))
```

Check this reference too: [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with dateutil parser

Before Using dateutil , install it using `pip install python-dateutil`

```
from dateutil import parser

your_date_string = '2016-03-07 14:42:48.901013+05:30'

yourDate = parser.parse(your_date_string)
# yourDate -> datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 7, 14, 42, 48, 901013, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800))
```

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: Easy and good method @Mani kandan

Comment: thanks I got the datetime object but can you tell me how can I parse the date in the exact same format that i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Datetime object alone ,

```
a = '2016-03-07 14:42:48.901013+05:30'.split('+')[0]
get_dateiobj =  datetime.strptime(a,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

it will return upto your timezone

[dateutil also the](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) better method it seems like angularjs - momentjs .

You can parse multiple dateformat using this.

`pip install python-dateutil`
than you can parse different format like,

```
from dateutil.parser import *
now = parse("2016-03-07 14:42:48.901013+05:30")
```