# How to translate datetime string to sql format?

Tags: python, datetime

Is there any shorter method to translate this ISO 8601 compatible UTC time to the SQL DATETIME format?

```
>>> str = "2016-03-28T20:23:46+0800"
>>> temp = str.split('T')
>>> temp[1] = temp[1].rstrip('+')
>>> temp[1]
'20:23:46+0800'
>>> temp[1] = temp[1].split('+')[0]
>>> result = " ".join(temp)
>>> result
'2016-03-28 20:23:46'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I hope you're not planning on formatting or catenating this result to a query string.

Comment: I'm planning to write it as a tuple's attribute, yes, and what?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime

Comment: If by writing it as a tuple's attribute you mean insert it to a table, I mean that manually constructing query strings and passing values by formatting or concatenating them in to the query string is a very bad thing to do. I'm not saying you're doing so, but asking. DB-API's handle passing proper `datetime` objects as arguments to a placeholder query correctly.

Comment: if you use Python bindings for your sql db then it should be able to convert a datetime object  automatically i.e., all you need is to convert the string into `datetime` object. It is more likely that you won't introduce timezone-related  errors in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply switch formats:

```
>>> date_str = "2016-03-28T20:23:46+0800"
>>> format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
>>> new_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' 
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, format).strftime(new_format)
'2016-03-28 20:23:46'
```

This will not work in python 2.x as it does not support the `%z` flag. See [timezone python 2 support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282040/3125566) for a workaround

Comment: in Python 2 you will have a problem with the %z. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime

Comment: @lesingerouge Thanks for noting. I've added the link you provided for python 2.x support.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this.
Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime) for more details on possible solutions.

If you're looking for a quick hack try this:

```
st = '2016-03-28T20:23:46+0800'
st[:19].replace("T", " ")
```

Or, if you need the date in datetime:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(st[:19], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: >>> str
'2016-03-28T20:23:46+0800'
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").isoformat(" ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2016-03-28T20:23:46+0800' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'