# How to convert a timestamp string with 7 digits on the microseconds part using strptime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

Having a timestamp as string like `2016-09-22T13:57:31.2311892-04:00`, how can one get the datetime object?

I've tried using `strptime` for this, but I got two issues:

- I need to remove `:` from the timezone part, at the end, for `%z` to work properly.
- The microseconds part has 7 digits, but `strptime` handles only up to 6 digits.

Is there a way to parse timestamps in this format without modifying* the string itself before passing to `strptime`?

* - by modifying, I think of removing the last microsecond digit, and removing the last `:`.

Note: This is for inserting a record in MySQL. If that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime)

Comment: @pktangyue this is not a duplicate question. I'm asking how to handle two different extra characters using the method, not how to make the conversion itself.

Comment: In python2 `strptime` do not support 7 digits microseconds and `%z` for timezone. That means using a third lib will be a better way.

Comment: Using python 3 here.

Comment: You said 'removing the last microsecond digit, and removing the last :'. This may be simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about convert like this:

```
dt = datetime.strptime(s[:-len('2-04:00')], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
# datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 22, 13, 57, 31, 231189)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Suddenly found a useful method at django:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
dt = parse_datetime('2016-09-22T13:57:31.2311892-04:00')
# datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 22, 13, 57, 31, 231189, tzinfo=<django.utils.timezone.FixedOffset object at 0x7f20184f8390>)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.dateparse

> Another pythonic format (use `maya` https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya):

```
# pip install maya
import maya
maya.parse('2016-09-22T13:57:31.2311892-04:00').datetime()
# datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 22, 17, 57, 31, 231189, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: So you are saying that basically I don't need the timezone info? Maybe I can store it in another column? Now that I think of it, it makes sense. This would allow a conversion on-the-fly, based on the user's timezone. Was that your thought?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira I edit my answer and fix the timezone.