# Converting string to datetime with milliseconds and timezone - Python

Tags: python

I have the following python snippet:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = '05/Jan/2015:17:47:59:000-0800'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%d/%m/%y:%H:%M:%S:%f-%Z')
print datetime_object
```

However when I execute the code, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '05/Jan/2015:17:47:59:000-0800' does not match format '%d/%m/%y:%H:%M:%S:%f-%Z'
```

what's wrong with my matching expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT 2:** According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282040/6011718), `strptime` doesn't support `%z` (despite what the documentation suggests). To get around this, you can just ignore the timezone adjustment?:

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = '05/Jan/2015:17:47:59:000-0800'
# only take the first 24 characters of `timestamp` by using [:24]
dt_object = datetime.strptime(timestamp[:24], '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%f')
print(dt_object)
```

Gives the following output:

```
$ python date.py
2015-01-05 17:47:59
```

---

**EDIT:** Your `datetime.strptime` argument should be `'%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%f-%z'`

With `strptime()`, `%y` refers to

> Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number

I.e. `01`, `99`, etc.

If you want to use the full 4-digit year, you need to use `%Y`

Similarly, if you want to use the 3-letter month, you need to use `%b`, not `%m`

I haven't looked at the rest of the string, but there are possibly more mismatches. You can find out how each section can be defined in the table at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: That mismatch is fine... I'm more worried with the milliseconds and the timezone ... could you help me with that?

Comment: It's all listed in the table in the link I gave you

Comment: @cybertextron edited my post to have the string of identifiers you should be using

Comment: when I run with `timestamp='05/Jan/2015:17:47:59:000-0800'` I'm getting `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%f%z'` ...

Comment: @cybertextron I'm getting that too, looking into it. In the mean time, if you change your date string to `timestamp='05/Jan/2015:17:47:59:000-UTC'`, the following argument for `strptime` works: `%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%f-%Z`

Comment: @cybertextron Updated my post, I've got a solution

Answer (score 0):

And UTC offset is lowercase z.

Comment: If I hadd `%z` I'm getting the following error: `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%f%z'`