# How can I convert '2020-09-30 23:45:27+0000' to date object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I'm trying

```
date_st = '2020-09-30 23:45:27+0000'
daate_ob= datetime.strptime(date_st,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z" )
```

but it returned ValueError: time data '2020-09-30 23:4527+0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z

Comment: what does the 4527+0000 represent?

Comment: A colon is missing between minutes and seconds.

Comment: You are right but the error now is ValueError: time data '2020-09-30 23:45:27+0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f%z'

Comment: sooo the +1000 part are milisec right?

Comment: No. the +xxxx portion is the timezone data.

Comment: The `%f` doesn't match anything in that string, get rid of it.

Comment: Yeah, actually datetime.strptime(date_st,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z" ) works fine. Thank You.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string to datetime with milliseconds and timezone - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539074/converting-string-to-datetime-with-milliseconds-and-timezone-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the format of your date you should use this:

```
date_st = '2020-09-30 23:45:27+0000'
daate_ob= datetime.strptime(date_st,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z" )
```