# How to parse Fri, 25 Jun 2021 12:06:16 +0000 (UTC) to datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

If there was no (UTC), it would be:
`%a, %d %b %Y %X %z`
but server is sending with additional (UTC) or (CDT) how do you parse it?
`%a, %d %b %Y %X %z (%Z)` doesn't work.

Comment: I hope you have stripped out the extra spaces, if any...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert timestamps with offset to datetime obj using strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281975/convert-timestamps-with-offset-to-datetime-obj-using-strptime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does it not work? Which version of python are you using?
I just ran the following in python 3.9:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("Fri, 25 Jun 2021 12:06:16 +0000 (UTC)", "%a, %d %b %Y %X %z (%Z)")
```

Which created this datetime object:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 25, 12, 6, 16, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0), 'UTC'))
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad I made a very silly mistake‍♂️.Thank you.